# Combine Publishers.Merge but with Publishers.combineLatest behaviour

Tags: swift, combine

I am currently trying to implement the merging of two publishers. But I can't find a solution for my use case.

I want to merge 2 publishers that both emit an array of structs of the same type. I want the combined publisher to emit values when either one of the merged publishers emit a new value.

Basically this would be a use case for `Publishers.CombineLatest`, but since my underlying publishers both emit values of the same type a `merge` would be more fitting here. But `Publishers.Merge` will not remember the last values of the merged publishers.

Therefore I would like to have a `Publishers.CombineLatest` behaviour with a `Publishers.Merge` operation. Is there something inside the Combine framework which can accomplish this kind of behaviour ?

**Rough example what should happen:**

```
Definitions:

PublisherA: emits -> [Value]
PublisherB emits -> [Value]

CombinedAB: -> [Value]


PublisherA changes: CombinedAB -> [NewA, OldB]
PublisherB changes: CombinedAB -> [OldA, NewB]
```

```swift
let a = CurrentValueSubject<[Int], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let b = CurrentValueSubject<[Int], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])

let combined = Publisher.AnyThing(a, b)

combined.sink {
   print($0)
}


b.send(["g", "h", "i"])


Outputs:
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
["a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "i"]
```

So it's basically a `Publishers.CombineLatest` but without emitting a tuple of (NewA,OldB) but instead already merged, because both values have the same type.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what are you expecting as output giving some examples?

Comment: @FabioFelici I added an example and how this makes things more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your combine operation is just concat of the subarrays you can do:

```swift
let a = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let b = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])

let combined = Publishers.CombineLatest(a, b).map(+)

combined.sink {
   print($0)     //["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] and ["a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "i"]
}


b.send(["g", "h", "i"])
```

I am not completely sure what you mean with "already merged". 
If you want to have the latest emitted array always at the end of the combined array then you might need a `scan` operator before the `map(+)` to be able to compare with previous emissions and swap them.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This would assume that my arrays of my custom type conform to AdditiveArithmetic protocol, correct ? I added a code example which basically requires what you have done, but I think the `Publishers.Merge` does not require types to conform to the mentioned protocols, which is the behaviour I would prefer.

Comment: You don't need to deal with `AdditiveArithmetic` at all because you are concatenating two arrays of the same type.

Comment: Publishers.CombineLatest(a, b).map(+)   please update your answer

Comment: @FabioFelici you are right, I do not have to deal with `AdditiveArithmetic `. I had some errors further down in my publishers chain, that's why I got this error. So your solution works and I will accept it, thanks a lot ! But it still relies on combineLatest with I can only add up to 4 publishers to. Maybe there will be some solution in the future which will accept n publishers that can be merged with CombineLatest

Comment: Note that `Publisher` has a `combineLatest` method you can use for even more brevity: `let combined = a.combineLatest(b, +)`.

Comment: Using this I made a generic function here: https://gist.github.com/kshivang/ae1315c497d59d2dea9e326dace59dfe

Answer (score 2):

## Problem Overview

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/combinelatest(_:)) explain the differences between three approaches for combining Publishers:

> Use `combineLatest(_:)` when you want the downstream subscriber to
> receive a tuple of the most-recent element from multiple publishers
> when any of them emit a value. To pair elements from multiple
> publishers, use `zip(_:)` instead. To receive just the most-recent
> element from multiple publishers rather than tuples, use `merge(with:)`.

`Zip` and `CombineLatest` are the only appropriate solution for consuming events **together** in real-time. In your particular example (ordering of sending events) `CombineLatest` is the best solution, as explained below.

### `CombineLatest`

You are right that `CombineLatest` does listen to events from nested Publishers, however prints `Publisher` elements using a tuple. This can be easily fixed using `map`, or `compactMap` depending on the Array generic parameter. `CombineLatest` publishes only the latest unconsumed events once both Publishers have published an element. This means that once both publishers have published an event, then **all** subsequent events will be published.

#### Listening Usage Demo

```
let a = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let b = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])
a 
  .combineLatest(b, +)
  .sink { print("\($0)") }
  .store(in: &cancellableSet)
b.send(["g", "h", "i"])

// ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
// ["a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "i"]
```

### `Merge`

`Publishers.Merge` may seem more appropriate because of the same `Output` Generic type, however it isn't. `Merge` only receives the latest published element for an individual `Publisher`. So, we can't print the combined stream even though we've "merged" the Publishers. The documentation refers to `Merge` as creating an **[interleaved stream](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers-merge-publisher-operators)** rather than a combined Publisher.

### Merge Listening Usage Demo:

```
let a = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let b = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])

let combined = Publishers.Merge(a, b)

combined.sink {
  print($0)
}
.store(in: &cancellableSet)

b.send(["g", "h", "i"])

// ["a", "b", "c"]
// ["d", "e", "f"]
// ["g", "h", "i"]
```

### `Zip`

`Zip` is a viable alternative to `CombineLatest` and both are valid options for printing combined Publisher events. The difference is that `Zip` publishes the oldest unconsumed event when waiting for the other Publisher.

#### Listening Usage Demo

```
let a = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let b = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])
a 
  .zip(b).map(+)
  .sink { print("\($0)") }
  .store(in: &cancellableSet)
b.send(["g", "h", "i"])

// ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

// To print "g","h","i", we need `a` to send an event.

a.send(["a", "b", "c"])
// ["a", "b", "c", "g", "h", "i"]
```

## Summary

Use `combineLatest` for printing **combined** publisher events. Use `zip` for printing **combined** publisher events when **both** publishers have to be **in sync**. Use `merge` when you want to listen to both `Publisher` events **individually**. `Merge` works well for creating a single interleaved event stream. If either upstream publisher finishes successfully or fails with an error, the zipped/combined/merged publisher does the same. Carefully consider which operator to use for your particular application NOT only by type signature but by *actual behaviour* instead.

### Bonus Notes

If you want to combine more than 4 `Publishers` (why?), you can actually use nested `Publishers.CombineLatest4` with another `Publishers.CombineLatest`. SwiftUI uses this technique to combine more than 10 SwiftUI `View`s in a single `ViewBuilder`.

#### Code Example

```
let a = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let b = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])
let c = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["g", "h", "i"])
let d = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["j", "k", "l"])

let e = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["a", "b", "c"])
let f = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["d", "e", "f"])
let g = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["g", "h", "i"])
let h = CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never>(["j", "k", "l"])

let combinedOne = Publishers.CombineLatest4(a, b, c, d)
let combinedTwo = Publishers.CombineLatest4(e, f, g, h)
let combined = Publishers.CombineLatest(combinedOne, combinedTwo)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning nested CombineLatest publishers. I was wondering about whether that's a valid approach.